# LIMIT is ignored in query with into outfile

Tags: mysql, sql

I have interesting problem in Mysql. I have this query:

```
SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = 1000000000000;
SELECT group_concat(`status` separator ' ') FROM tweet_train_sentiment LIMIT 5
INTO OUTFILE 'C:\\Users\\Jirda\\Desktop\\tweet_train.txt';
```

And If I run it, the result doesn'T contain only 5 instances but it contains all the instances from tweet_train_sentiment.

Why the limit is ignored and is it possible to get it right?

Thank you

Petr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GROUP_CONCAT doens't work with LIMIT
Have a look at the documentaition : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat

Comment: Maybe you could try derived table like this [not tested] : SELECT * FROM (SELECT group_concat(`status` separator ' ') FROM tweet_train_sentiment) dt limit 5

Answer (score 1):

If you want only five values in the outfile, use either `substring_index()` or a subquery:

```
SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = 1000000000000;

SELECT group_concat(`status` separator ' ')
FROM (SELECT tts.*
      FROM tweet_train_sentiment
      LIMIT 5
     ) tts
INTO OUTFILE 'C:\\Users\\Jirda\\Desktop\\tweet_train.txt';
```